# I'm trying to add "grades" to an array and it isn't going as planned

Tags: javascript, arrays, user-input

The idea for this is to enter a "grade" or a general number, check to make sure that it is a number, ad it to the grade array, and then for each number added create a list item containing an input which contains the entered number.

I have 2 functions. The first one called ,check(), assigns the input value to the userInput variable, then checks that the variable is a number. if it is then it calls the adTo() function which is supposed to push the userInput variable into the grade[] array then update the list. This however is not what happens. here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <Title>Ultimate Grader</title>

    <style>

    </style>
    <script>


        function check(){
            var userInput = document.getElementById('grade').value;

            if ( isNaN(userInput) || userInput === " ") {
                alert("please enter a Number");
            }else {
                adTo(userInput);
            };
        }


        function adTo(input) {
            var grade = [];

            grade.push(input);

            for (i=0; i<=grade.length; i++){
                document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<li><input type='number' value='" + grade[i] + "'/></li>";
            };

            };

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
    <input type="text" id="grade" name="grade" placeholder="Grade">
    <input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Add" onclick="check()">
    </form>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please put back the original code. My answer doesn't make sense without it. If you want to show the new code, add it as an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `adTo()`, you're creating a new, empty array. You need to define the variable outside the function, so it will retain its value between calls.

Also, your `for()` loop is replacing the `innerHTML` each time through the loop, it's not appending to it. Use `+=` to append.

```
var grade = [];
function adTo(input) {
    grade.push(input);
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.innerHTML = ''; // Empty it
    for (var i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
        list.innerHTML += "<li><input type='number' value='" + grade[i] + "'/></li>";
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/eoeogfhs/)

There isn't really much need for that loop, though. Since the list should already have the items from previous calls, all you really need to do is append the new one:

```
function adTo(input) {
    grade.push(input);
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += "<li><input type='number' value='" + input + "'/></li>";
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/eoeogfhs/1/)

Comment: Thanks that fixed it up, however now when I click to activate the function it ads each item in the array to the list with the first one being "undefined". so it starts out "undefined", then "undefined" undefined" "90", then "undefined" "undefined" "90" "undefined" "undefined" "90" "81", etc. Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: I made a mistake in the last version, it should put `input` into the HTML, not `grade[i]`. Is that the one causing the problem?

Comment: Thank you Barmar. I removed the for loop around my assignment to #lists innerHtml and changed grade[i] to input and it now works perfectly.